# Small caps in Libertinus not available after upgrade to Texlive 2020

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, ubuntu, texlive-2020, libertinus

I am using the Libertinus font inside a Tikz figure, including text with small caps. This used to work fine with Texlive 2019 (installed via Ubuntu's package manager). However, after updating to the latest Ubuntu and Texlive 2020, I get messages such as these:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n' instead on input line 103
```

And the font is visibly wrong. Here is a complete document which has the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm]
    \node at (0, 0) {\scshape Testing};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I purged the old installation of Texlive before installing the new one.

These are the Ubuntu Texlive packages installed in my system:

```
texlive
texlive-base
texlive-binaries
texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-extra-links
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-luatex
texlive-pictures
texlive-plain-generic
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here?

EDIT: You can find the full log from running `lualatex testing.tex` here: https://pastebin.com/AQiKxL9u

Comment: As always on this site, please extend to a full example. Given that Ubuntu split texlive into a bunch of Ubuntu packages, it would be nice to know exactly which texlive Ubuntu packages you have installed. Note that the rest of us are now on texlive 2021.

Comment: Thanks daleif! I have made the edits you suggested.

Comment: Your mwe works correctly unter 2021 version (mactex).

Comment: No idea, I can test against upstream texlive 2021 tomorrow. I think there were some changes to the libertinus fonts at some  point. Have you checked the manual for the package?

Comment: No issues on TL21. Could you provide the full log from your compilation of MWE.

Comment: I cannot find anything relevant in the package's manual. I think I'm going to try purging Ubuntu's Texlive 2020 packages and installing Texlive 2021 manually. Is tlmgr the standard way to go?

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you on? I looked (`apt-file`) on Ubuntu 18.04 and it does not have `libertinus.sty`

Comment: I just added a Pastebin link with the full log: https://pastebin.com/AQiKxL9u

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: You also never mentioned you were using `lualatex`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I assumed that's what everybody is using these days... ;-)

Comment: Not really vast majority still on pdflatex, plus lualatex is still slower than pdflatex...

Comment: Please tag the question with `lualatex`. I can confirm that the OTF fonts seems to have an issue there in TL21 as well, the Type1 fonts with pdflatex does not.

Comment: You're right. The font shows up correctly with pdflatex.

Comment: why do you use T1 encoding with lualatex?

Comment: With LuaLaTeX, does removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` make it work? That should use the OpenType fonts.

Comment: As others mentioned (should have remembered this), there is no issues under `lualatex` once `fontenc` is removed as it is not relevant for `lualatex`.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the problem goes away once I remove the fontenc. Thank you everybody!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...